# AWS EC2 default password

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-ec2

I'm following [this](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-apache#5-activating-virtualhost-file) tutorial to host a website with an apache server. The thing is that the last step tells my to do

```
service apache2 reload
```

But it asks me for a password. I don't remember inserting a password for this VM, just the .pem I used to log in.

Is there a default password? Or how can I solve this? Sorry if this is basic, but the most complex thing I've done with servers is with wamp and xamp

Thanks!

Comment: what about `sudo service apache2 reload`?

Comment: Wow, I thought about it but thought it had no sense. By any chance, can you explain why with sudo it doesn't ask for a passowrd? I thought it would be the opposite. Thanks!

Comment: You can read more details elsewhere how to setup `sudo` to not use password, e.g. [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147241/execute-sudo-without-password). If you don't mind I will make awns er that the `sudo` was the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments, the solution was to use `sudo`:

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```